# Make mouse-3 behave like mouse-1 (mouse-set-point) only for overlays

Tags: mouse, overlays

I defined this keymap:

```el
(defvar my-custom-keymap
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [mouse-1] #'my-function1)
    (define-key map [mouse-3] #'my-function2)
    map)
  "Custom Keymap")
```

Then I use:

```el
(overlay-put this-overlay 'keymap my-custom-keymap)
```

to set the key-binding on some overlays.

Both `my-function1` and `my-function2` works on overlays using the `(thing-at-point)` function, but only the first one works like I aspected because `mouse-1` event runs `(mouse-set-point)` and than `my-function1`.

`mouse-3` event doesn't move the "point" so it doesn't see the "thing-at-point" where the mouse has been clicked.

Can I make `mouse-3` event behave like `mouse-1` event only for overlays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```el
(defvar my-custom-keymap
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [mouse-1] #'my-function1)
    (define-key map [mouse-3] '(lambda ()
                                 (interactive)
                                 (mouse-set-point last-input-event)
                                 (my-function2)))
    map)
  "Custom Keymap")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have `function2` call `mouse-set-point` before calling `thing-at-point`.

Comment: Thanks, I made that `(mouse-set-point)` is called by a `lamda` function in the `keymap`.